# Stored procedure that creates a table with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a stored procedure which takes a dynamic number of parameters and creates a SQL table based on the parameters given to it.

I know initially that there will be 7 columns, but there could be more.

I am working in Snowflake.

Comment: How do you get the parameters? If for example they come as a result of a SQL statement, you can run that inside the stored procedure and store them in variables and create after the table with them. The stored procedure would need no arguments in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters need to be defined in the Stored Proc.
To pass a variable numbers of parms, you can pass the parameters as a delimited list in a string, so you are passing a single string parameter, then the stored procedure can split the string and loop through each element of the array.

```
MYVAR = 'A~B~C';

CREATE PROCEDURE PROCABC(MYVAR VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var ARRAY_STR = MYVAR.split("~");
//process ARRAY_STR in a loop
```

Comment: In addition to a delimited string, the input parameter could also be a VARIANT or an ARRAY.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this, definitely the way to go about it
Thank you:)